# How to distinguish between voice call and video call on Android?

Tags: android, video, voice

I want to log voice call and video call. I must distinguish them.
Where is the difference between the intent for ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL of video call and the intent for ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL of voice call?

Comment: please let me know how can I initiate Video call if I have phone number. Is there any method like we do voice call by intent?? or we need to compulsorily develope our own voice calling functionality?

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference, because there are no video calls in Android at the time of this writing. Any video chat application will not be using `ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` in all likelihood, so all broadcasts of `ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` are for voice calls.

Comment: Thanks.I found the difference. In the ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL broadcast receiver: Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();  Object callType = bundle.get("android.phone.extra.calltype"); If it is a video call,callType is an integer of 2.