# Check if any audio or video incoming or outgoing call on my device

Tags: android, android-activity, video-streaming, avaudioplayer, microphone

I am making a android application . App send notification if any audio or video call comes on device .
Can any body tell me, How i can detect if any outgoing or incoming audio or video call happens ..

Eg: Like Skype call , viber call etc
Thanks in Advance .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537924/how-to-distinguish-between-voice-call-and-video-call-on-android

Comment: Hi Raghunandan, My question is how can i detect if a  voice call like skype call or viber happen

Comment: hii i have use reveiver ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL <receiver
            android:name="com.safeword.receiver.IncommingCallReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver> but this does not call broadcast receiver when i do skype call